# Finding the max and average difference

Tags: excel

I have a small data-set with reference values and measured values

```
0   0.017
5   5.2
10  11.2
15  14.4
20  20.5
25  25.5
30  31.2
35  37.6
40  40.2
42  42.8
44  43.1
46  44.7
48  47.2
50  50.3
52  53
```

I would like to know what the max difference and the average difference is between the reference and measured data. How is this done in Excel?

Comment: I assume that you want to take absolute differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Max difference using an array formula. You will need to hold `Control + Shift` when you press `Enter` after typing the array formula in the cell where you want to compute that value.   If you don't hold `Control + Shift` while entering the formula then it won't work correctly.

For example, if you have the referenced values in `A1:A15` and measured values in `B1:B15`, you can type `=Max(Abs(B1:B15-A1:A15))` into a cell, then hold `Control + Shift` and press `Enter` to enter the formula as an array formula. That will give you the maximum difference between the values, regardless of whether the measured value is higher or lower than the referenced value.

The Average can be done the same way, just use `=Average(Abs(B1:B15-A1:A15))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
=MAX(ABS(reference-measured))
```

entered as an array formula CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER

Comment: Bummer, it goes three hours without an answer and then you beat me by a minute. Well done. :)

Comment: That's cause I banged out a quickie answer and you took the time to give a more helpful and thorough explanation